# Prove that the ratio between the sines is equal to that of the sides.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Can you please help me prove that the ratio between the sines of the angles in a triangle is equal to the ratio between the sides of the same triangle:

$$\frac{\sin A}{\sin B \cdot \sin C} = \frac{a}{b \cdot c}$$

Where side a for example is the side opposite to $\angle A$ and same for sides $b$ and $c$.

This equation was introduced to me in class when we where trying to solve a problem:

In $\bigtriangleup$$ABC$, $\sin A:\sin B:\sin C = 2:3:4$. What is the size of the greatest angle in $\bigtriangleup$$ABC$?

The solution I was provided by my teacher included the stated equation without a proof. Keep in mind we only learned the sine and the cosine laws.

Comment: The identity $$\frac{\sin A}{\sin B \cdot \sin C} = \frac{a}{b \cdot c}$$ does not hold in general. The law of sines implies that the triple ratios $\sin A : \sin B : \sin C$ and $a : b : c$ are equal; we cannot interpret this as division and try to conclude that $(\sin A/\sin B)/\sin C$ and $(a/b)/c$ are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Equating two expressions for the area of a triangle gives$$\frac12bc\sin A=\frac12ca\sin B\implies\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}.$$(In fact, [we can prove](https://geome3atc.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/the-extended-law-of-sines/) this ratio is twice the triangle's circumradius.)